# Get text in one tag BS4 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have HTML code. I need to get the full text of only 1 tag. I use get_text (), but I still get the text of the next tags.
**HTML:**

```html
<div class="test__title" data-intro="intro">
    "The first text I need"
    "The second text I need"
    <p class="test__title__promt">
        "I do not need it"
        "I do not need it"
    <p class="test__title__second__promt">
        "I do not need it"
        "I do not need it"
```

**Python:**

```py
test_title = soup.find('div', class_='test__title')
print(test_title.get_text())
```

Result:

```
The first text I need
The second text I need
I do not need it
I do not need it
I do not need it
I do not need it
```

Desired result:

```
The first text I need
The second text I need
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *html in your question is not valid, so the output may differ slightly*

One approach could be to get the `contents` of the element and grab the first element of the resultset:

```
soup.find('div', class_='test__title').contents[0]
```

or use a list comprehension to pick only none tags:

```
' '.join([e.strip() for e in soup.find('div', class_='test__title') if e.name == None])
```

Output:

```
"The first text I need"\n    "The second text I need"
```